# When should I use OutputCollector and Context in Hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

In [this](http://www.science.smith.edu/dftwiki/index.php/Hadoop_Tutorial_1_--_Running_Wordcount_(rev_2)) article I found this mapper code for word count:

```
  public static class MapClass extends MapReduceBase
    implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, 
                    OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, 
                    Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
      String line = value.toString();
      StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(line);
      while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(itr.nextToken());
        output.collect(word, one);
      }
    }
  }
```

Instead, in the [official tutorial](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Mapper) this is the provided mapper:

```
  public static class TokenizerMapper
       extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
      while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(itr.nextToken());
        context.write(word, one);
      }
    }
  }
```

Up to now, I've seen only `Context` to write something from the mapper to the reducer, I've never seen (or used) `OutputCollector`. I've read the [documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/OutputCollector.html), but I don't understand its key of use or why should I use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both code contains different API of Map Reduce.`OutputCollector` is in MRV1 and `Context` is in MRV2

> The Java Map Reduce API 1 also known as MRV1 was released with initial hadoop versions and the flaw associated with these initial versions was map reduce framework performing both the task of processing and resource management.
>
> Map Reduce 2 or the Next Generation Map Reduce, was a long-awaited and much-needed upgrade to the techniques concerned with scheduling, resource management, and the execution occurring in Hadoop. Fundamentally, the improvements separate cluster resource management capabilities from Map Reduce-specific logic and this separation of processing and resource management were achieved via inception of YARN in later versions of HADOOP.

MRV1 uses `OutputCollecter` and `Reporter` to communicate with the MapReduce system.

MRV2 uses API to make extensive use of `context` objects that allow the user code to communicate with the MapReduce system. (The role of the JobConf, the OutputCollector, and the Reporter from the old API is unified by Contexts objects in MRV2).

Use should use mapreduce 2 (MRV2).I have highlighted hadoop 2's biggest advantages over hadoop:

1. One major advantage is, there are no jobtrackers and tasktrackers in the
   hadoop2 architecture.  We have YARN resource manager and node
   manager instead. This helps hadoop2 support other models apart from
   mapreduce framework to execute the code and overcome high latency
   problems associated with mapreduce.
2. Hadoop2 supports non-batch processing along with traditional batch
   operations.
3. Hdfs federation is introduced in hadoop2. This enables multiple
   namenodes to control hadoop cluster which tries to handle single
   point failure problem of hadoop.

There are many more advantages of MRV2. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/

Answer (score -3):

This is a good solution, however, I just use the 1 line solution which is:
int wordcount = string.split(" ").length - 1;

Comment: I don't see at all how this is related to the question.